# Pass variable to getJSON jQuery function from closure scope

Tags: jquery, json, scope

I am trying to attach the same **jQuery** and **JSON ASP.NET MVC3 Method** to two different `<select>` elements:

```
<select id="StartYear">
<option value="">Select Year</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
</select>

<select id="StartMonth">
<option value="">Select Month</option>
</select>
```

Same applies for `<select>` elements with ids **"EndYear"** and **"EndMonth"**.

I want to attach to both "Start Year" and "End Year" the same jQuery function:

```
$('[id$="Year"]').change(function () {
        var selectedYear = $(this).val();
        var selectedId = $(this).attr('id')
        if (selectedYear != null && selectedYear != '') {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Months")', { year: selectedYear }, function (months) {
                var monthsSelect = $('#StartMonth');
                if (selectedId == 'EndYear') {
                    monthsSelect = $('#EndMonth');
                }
                monthsSelect.empty();
                daysSelect.prepend("<option text='-- select month --' value='' selected='selected'></option>");
                $.each(months, function (index, month) {
                    monthsSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: month.value,
                        text: month.text
                    }));
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

However, this code does not work. I debugged it with Bugzilla and I found out that this condition `(selectedId == 'EndYear')` breaks the function. The variable selectedId is in the closure scope but I don't know how to bring it inside the function scope. Otherwise I don't know what it cna be the cause.
Keep in mind that without that condition the code was working (of course just with #StartMonth)

Comment: How does it break? Does it give any error?

Comment: What's the selectedId outside of the getJSON method? (so, `console.log($(this).attr('id'));` after the assignment? )

Comment: thanks! before it gives StartDate then undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem the variable `selectedId` can do be accessed inside of success handler of `$.getJSON`, but the value of the variable can be already changed by another `change` event.

For example if two `change` events will be stated in short time interval from for example "#EndYear" and "#StartYear" then could be the following

1. `change` events for "#EndYear" will be triggered
2. `selectedId` variable will be set to "EndYear"
3. first `$.getJSON` will be started
4. `change` events for "#StartYear" will be triggered
5. `selectedId` variable will be set to "StartYear"
6. second `$.getJSON` will be started
7. first `$.getJSON` will be finished and the value of `selectedId` variable will be "StartYear" inside of the `success` handler
8. second `$.getJSON` will be finished and the value of `selectedId` variable will be "StartYear" inside of the `success` handler

So I think that you need just need to have *different instances* of `selectedId` variable to use the value which was before the `$.getJSON` took place. You can implement that in different way. It seems the most native for me to replace `$.getJSON` to `$.ajax` and to use `context` parameter of `$.ajax`. The code could be about the following

```
$('[id$="Year"]').change(function () {
    var selectedYear = $(this).val();
    var selectedId = $(this).attr('id')
    if (selectedYear != null && selectedYear != '') {
        //$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Months")', {year: selectedYear}, function(months){
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Months")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { year: selectedYear },
            context: {selectedId: selectedId},
            success: function (months) {
                var selectedId = this.selectedId; // get from context
                ....
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks Oleg, my problem is much easier. I don not understand why selectedId before the $.getJSON is equal to "StartDate" or "EndDate" and inside the function is undefined

Comment: @CiccioMiami: You are welcome! In any way what I suggest is to save the value of the `selectedId` in **new object** which you will access inside of `success` callback. In the case you will be sure that you will have unchanged value of `selectedId` inside of `success` callback.

Comment: @CiccioMiami: I have another idea which can be the reason of your problem: [the event bubbling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Event_flow) or some effect based on it. If you register `change` event on the element then all changes of the *children* follow calling of the `change` event handler. So you could have probably more changes of `selectedId` which you though. I recommend you to include `console.log` inside of the event handler and analyse the results. You will probably see when `selectedId` variable will be reset to `undefined` (when `$(this).attr('id')` return `undefined`).